# fullcalendar is adding minutes to my start time

Tags: fullcalendar

Has anyone using fullCalendar by Adam Shaw seen this before?  The start time showing up in the calendar gets minutes added, however, when I click on the event and get the popup, I see the correct time.

For example, there are 3 events on different days and all of them have start time of 9:00a but when the calendar (weekly, daily or monthly) gets displayed, all times have 8 minutes added to them so it reads 9:08a
When I click on any of the events and I get the popup, the start time shows correctly 9:00a.

I have checked the database where these events are being read from and they are correct.  Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates your issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can since this is integrated into NopCommerce.  To add more to this, I purchased a plugin from Nop4You and just noticed that even their demo page (http://demo.nopcommerce.pl/eventCalendar) exhibits the same issues.  I have opened a ticket with their support to see if this is something they should be fixing and not a fullCalendar issue.